# awk - understanding how FS works

Tags: awk, delimiter

I know that default FS= " ", then why am i seeing variations in following awk commands. Please help me understand.

```
>echo "   ABC DEF   XYZ  \n   abc       def,ghi   xyz   \n" | awk '{printf("nf: %s 1:%s line: %s\n", NF, $1, $0)}'
nf: 3 1:ABC line:    ABC DEF   XYZ  
nf: 3 1:abc line:    abc       def,ghi   xyz   
nf: 0 1: line: 
                                                                                                                                                               
>echo "   ABC DEF   XYZ  \n   abc       def,ghi   xyz   \n" | awk -F" " '{printf("nf: %s 1:%s line: %s\n", NF, $1, $0)}'
nf: 3 1:ABC line:    ABC DEF   XYZ  
nf: 3 1:abc line:    abc       def,ghi   xyz   
nf: 0 1: line: 
                                                                                                                                                               
>echo "   ABC DEF   XYZ  \n   abc       def,ghi   xyz   \n" | awk -F"[ ]" '{printf("nf: %s 1:%s line: %s\n", NF, $1, $0)}'
nf: 10 1: line:    ABC DEF   XYZ  
nf: 17 1: line:    abc       def,ghi   xyz   
nf: 0 1: line: 
                                                                                                                                                               
>echo "   ABC DEF   XYZ  \n   abc       def,ghi   xyz   \n" | awk -F"[ ]*" '{printf("nf: %s 1:%s line: %s\n", NF, $1, $0)}'
nf: 5 1: line:    ABC DEF   XYZ  
nf: 5 1: line:    abc       def,ghi   xyz   
nf: 0 1: line:
```

I want to understand why there are no **empty tokens** in 1st & 2nd examples, but exists in 3rd & 4th examples.

**Update**: To explain my doubt further, awk behaves inconsistently with default FS and custom FS. See below examples.

```
>printf "ab  cd\nef gh\n" | awk -F" " '{ printf("nf: %d\t", NF); for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%02d:%s\t", i, $i); print ""}'
nf: 2   01:ab   02:cd   
nf: 2   01:ef   02:gh

>printf "ab::cd\nef:gh\n" | awk -F":" '{ printf("nf: %d\t", NF); for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%02d:%s\t", i, $i); print ""}'
nf: 3   01:ab   02:     03:cd   
nf: 2   01:ef   02:gh
```

Comment: `echo` does not interpret `'\n'` or any control characters. Add `echo -e` (or just use `printf` for everything) Your `printf()` in `awk` should be `printf("nf: %s 1:%s line: %s\n", NF, FNR, $0)` (`FNR` file record number, `NR` total record number -- will be the same in your case) Or `$1` is fine if you want to print the first field in each record there...

Comment: Also `FS = " "` is essentially the default. (whitespace). You can omit that and the *field separator* will break the fields on space and tab characters by default. All the field separators you use mimic the default behavior.

Comment: If you are looking for examples, try `printf "a,b:c,d\ne,f:g,h\n" | awk -F, '{ printf "nf: %d\t", NF; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%-8s", $i; print ""}'` then change `FS` to `-F:`.

Comment: I am trying to understand the output difference for default vs -F"[ ]" & -F"[ ]*"

Comment: `F"[ ]" ` mandates each field-separator as a *Single-Space*. In `"   ABC DEF   XYZ  "` there are 10 space separators. In `-F"[ ]*"` the regular expression is *Zero-Or-More space* characters. In the first case, every space is a new field (3-empty fields before `"ABC"`), in the second case the first field is the only empty-field. I'd have to check to make sure this behavior would be consistent between `awk` versions.

Comment: Both -F" " and -F"[ ]" specifies field-separator as a single-space, then why they produce different outputs?
Also how can I specify delimiter as one-or-more of some characters, -F"[ ]+" did not work.

Comment: Because the REGEX `*` repetition qualifier means *zero-or-more occurrences* (of space), so your `FS` in that case is empty or as many spaces as there are between fields (default) . Actually I'm surprised `awk` doesn't puke on that one since from the zero or more standpoint the `FS` is ambiguously defined.

Comment: I understood about * (4th example). I was asking why 2nd & 3rd case produce different outputs where field-separator is just a single-space.

Comment: Because in the second case you have `" "` which is the default `FS` string, non regex. So it will match *one-or-more* whitespace characters as separators. In the third case you mandate *one-space-only* with the regex `"[ ]"`. Since the regex `[ ]` has no repeat qualifier it means verbatim -- every space.

Comment: Thank you. one last question, can we specify delimiter as one-or-more of some characters with [] ? , -F"[ ]+" did not work.

Comment: Yes, `awk` understands *Extended Regex* syntax, but the bigger question is why do you want to do this? In all these cases it is simple better to not set `FS` and use the default. Now you can  specify multiple `FS` using a regex specifier, and there are other circumstances where a regex `FS` is needed, but it is hard to see how messing with a space regex benefits you here unless you have a need to do it.

Comment: This was just an example, my FS is not space.

Comment: Updated the question with more clear example.

Comment: Post the first line of `awk --version` so I know what you are using. Read through [GNU Awk User's Guide - Specifying How Fields Are Separated](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html#Field-Separators) That explains why you see what you are seeing and the difference between string and regex separators, and then difference between whitespace and other values of `FS`. Keep [GNU Awk User's Guide Contents](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) it is a very good reference for `gawk` and `awk` showing how they differ as well.

Comment: >awk --version 
GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0

Comment: Perfect, the first two links in the page [GNU Awk User's Guide - Specifying How Fields Are Separated](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html#Field-Separators) explain exactly what is happening. When you use a space (default) `FS` any number of spaces are considered 1 separator. When you use a character (e.g. `':'`) each `':'` denotes a field. That's why a regex `[ ]` is different from the default and splits on every space.

Comment: Thank you. How can I mark your comments as answer ?

Comment: I'll write one up for you. Give me a few minutes `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `awk` uses a single space as the default `FS`. This is a *special* case and is the only special case. Two or more spaces are not interpreted as multiple fields, but as a single separator. Using *any other character* causes each occurrence of that character to be interpreted as a separator. So using `':'` will interpret `":::my"` as four fields. (`empty`, `empty`, `empty`, `"my"`) See: [GNU Awk User's Guide - 4.5.1 Whitespace Normally Separates Fields](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Default-Field-Splitting.html).

When you use a *Regular Expression*, each occurrence of the `FS` character (even a space) is considered a separate field separator. See [GNU Awk User's Guide - 4.5.2 Using Regular Expressions to Separate Fields](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Field-Splitting.html).

To examine every character as a separate field, you can simply set `FS` to the empty-string (null), either on the command line with `-F""` or by setting `FS = ""`.

In your examples where you use the Regex `-F"[ ]"` each space is considered a separate field separator. `FS` is a Regex and not the default case. It is a Regex where the single character just happens to be a space.

With the repetition of `*` (*zero-or-more*) occurrences, the `FS` is a bit ambiguous. It can match nothing (null) or it can match as many spaces as there are in a row. (which is why it matches the very first character and then multiple spaces) I do not recommend messing with spaces and `FS` in this manner.

`awk` understands *Extended Regular Expression* (ERE) syntax, so you can use the `'+'` repetition specifier for *one-or-more* occurrences of the character.

Keep the [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) handy. It is a good reference for `gawk` as well as the other flavors of `awk`. In the guide if something is unique to `gawk`, it will be marked with a `'#'` in the guide to tell you. It usually explains (sometimes in a footnote) how the `gawk` behavior is different than POSIX `awk` or `mawk`, etc..

Comment: just a small correction, -F="" should be -F""

Comment: Oops -- good eyes. I'm getting old... Fixing.